# Enumerating and using wmp visualizers

Tags: c++, com, winapi, wmp, visualizer

I want to use the systems available windows media player visualizers in my app. Apperently visualizers expose an [IWMPEffects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563253%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) interface to the world. My question is how do I enumerate and create instances to the available visualizers on my system? Probably it's just a process of getting the cslid of the visualizers and then create the instance with CoCreateInstance. However I have no idea how to get these clsid's!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLSIDs of the objects that implement `IWMPEffects` are stored as subkeys of `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Objects\Effects`.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, the info is definitely in the registry. However I only found one reference to visualizer and that's the "Viz plugin". I think this plugin looks up the installed visualizers in another place.

I have installed a viz which resides in "Pulsing.dll". A quick search for it in regedit gets me the clsid, but I have not been able to trace where this clsid comes from! 

Maybe use some tool to see what windows media player are pulling from the registry at startup?

Comment: Mmm the CLSID of the various visualizer have to be somewhere in the registry, otherwise WMP should enumerate the entire HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID, and that's not viable! However the key I provided in the answer was the most logical place...
If I remember correctly, also Windows Media Center uses the same visualizations, and as it is a .net application, you could check with Reflector ;)

Comment: I got it! Used process monitor from sysinternals to monitor what keys wmp read, searched for my known clsid and bang! Found that the visualizers are stored in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Objects\Effects

If you edit your post to reflect this revelation I'm tagging it as the solution ;)

Comment: Well done! Of course the answer seems so logical when you've discovered it! I edited the answer to reflect the correct registry key.